# Is it possible to run sls files parallel?

Tags: docker, salt-stack

I am running an sls file that starts up a docker container that should remain active in the background. It does work, the container is up and running. However, until I kill the containers on my minions, I am unable to run any other state.apply commands because I get:

```
 The function "state.apply" is running as PID 44455 and was started at 2020, Aug 19 18:49:13.242099 with jid 20200819184913242099
```

Now, I have found the following documentation: https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/parallel.html which would imply that it actually is possible. However, when I add it to my SLS file, it does not work. I am still unable to call a new state.apply until I kill the containers.
This is what my file looks like:

```
docker.io:
pkg.installed: []
require:
- pkgrepo: docker_prerequisites
- pkg: docker_prerequisites
service.running:
- parallel: True
- name: docker
- enable: True
- restart: True
- image: ubuntu
- port_bindings: 800:80

docker:
cmd.run:
- name: docker run -t  ubuntu
```

Am I using the command wrong? This is how I figured it should be based on the documentation. Or is there possibly a different way to start a docker container that stays active from an sls file?

Answer (score 0):

If you check your salt logs or your process manager, you will very likly be able to find out whats happening here. The state is running aslong as the command runs.
The problem is within your cmd.run. Salt executes the cmd.run as long as the command in it is being executed. Salt will only excecute the next cmd.run if no other cmd.run is currently running. Otherwise you will get your mentioned error.

```
- name: docker run -t  ubuntu
```

The command that you used would attach the containers shell. (-t) Therefore salt is waiting for the command to end. In this case the command will not end until you close the containers shell.
The solution is, to detach the containers shell so it is present as a background process and attach it afterwards.

```
docker:
cmd.run:
- name: docker run -t -d ubuntu
```

Simply by adding -d parameter you detach the containers shell and the container runs in the background. By adding this parameter, your saltstate should finish.

Now as the container runs in the background you can attach yourself to the containers shell with the following command:

```
docker exec -it <container_id> /bin/bash
```

---

However heres how you run saltstates parallel:

When applying a saltstate to your target minion, try to add the following parameter to your salt or salt-call command at the end: `concurrent=true`

Please refer to this documentation and search for concurrent: https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.state.html

This article describes the problem. However you should be careful with that as it could be dangerous to run the same salt module twice simultaneously. so try to avoid this.